# Objective C componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet

Tags: objective-c

I am using the `componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet` method in Objective C to read data from an array. It works fine when my array contains multiple parameters with the separator, but when my array has only one parameter the method return nothing. For example:

```
array = [x*y*z];

newAray = [array componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"*"]];

//returns newArray = [x,y,z] - this is good

array = [x];

newAray = [array componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"*"]];

//returns nothing - this is bad
```

Is there a way to fix this so the second example would return `newArray = [x]` without changing the format of the first array?

Comment: Append a separator char on the end before calling.

Comment: Posting real code is always better than fake code. For example, your first line certainly isn't valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"`componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet`" is a method that exists in "`NSString`", so for you to be able to use it, your "`array`" object needs to be a "`NSString`" object.

My solution would be to add a category on NSString which returns either an array of components separated by characters in the string, or the whole string if the array returned by that call is empty (which would happen if nothing matches to allow for separated components).

This is what the category would look like on NSString:

```
@interface NSString (AlwaysReturnSomething)

- (NSArray *) alwaysReturnSomethingForComponentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: (NSCharacterSet *) characterSet;

@end

@implementation NSString (AlwaysReturnSomething)

- (NSArray *) alwaysReturnSomethingForComponentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: (NSCharacterSet *) characterSet
{
    NSArray * arrayToReturn = [self componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: characterSet];
    if(arrayToReturn == NULL) || ([arrayToReturn count] == 0)
    {
        arrayToReturn = [NSArray arrayWithObject: self];
    }
    return(arrayToReturn);
}

@end
```

Comment: yeah I'm actually referring to a specific index in the array when I am using it. You can use it on array in this way.